# Disable scrolling in an iPhone web application?

Tags: javascript, iphone, scroll

Is there any way to completely disable web page scrolling in an iPhone web app? I've tried numerous things posted on google, but none seem to work.

Here's my current header setup:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

`document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: kendall, would you mind adding more of your code so I could see what went in... I'm pretty new to this - here's what i have that doesn't work: `<script language="javascript"> document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); </script>`

Comment: nevermind i used this: `document.ontouchmove = function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
}
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;'

Just add this one line in the 'viewDidLoad' of the mainViewController.m file of your application. you can open it in the Xcode and add it .

This should make the page without any rubberband bounces still enabling the scroll in the app view.

Comment: It's been awhile but this answer doesn't really seem to be for this question as it is describing how to avoid scrolling inside a scrollView of a native iOS app.

Answer (score 58):

Change to the `touchstart` event instead of `touchmove`.  Under [One Finger Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) it says that no events are sent during a pan, so `touchmove` may be too late.

I added the listener to document, not body.

**Example:**

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: You actually need to use both touchstart AND touchmove, or you can still get scrolling.

Comment: @jirapong would you mind adding more of your code so I could see what went in... I'm pretty new to this - here's what i have that doesn't work: `<script language="javascript">
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
</script>`

Comment: Do you testing with iPhone/iPad? If yes, then you can try to open Developer bar on Setting to see more detail. hope it help.

Comment: @jirapong, thanks. i used this: nevermind i used this: `document.ontouchmove = function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
}
`

Comment: this also kills all tap events, so nothing on the page is tappable.

Comment: It works albeit what about enabling touchmove again? what do we do then? I disable it on button click but after the event - it still remains in-scrollable.

Comment: found out how to enable the scrolling again - document.ontouchmove = function(e){ return true; }

Comment: I think they fixed this in iOS 5.  You don't need to prevent default on touchstart to prevent scrolling, so now everything can be tapped.  Device: iPad 2, iOS version 5.1.1.  It has to be on the document.

Comment: :D - Works perfectly as advertised in iOS 7! Just one question - is there anyway to hide the navigation and tool bars to give my web app the full screen?

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I have a modal with an overlay. Once I reach the end of the scroll content of the modal, then the content behind the overlay begins to scroll, even when using `$(document).on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  });`

Comment: I had posted similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25016369/261375 with still no answer as of 09/26/2014

Answer (score 19):

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Do not use the `ontouchmove` property to register the event handler as you are running at risk of overwriting an existing event handler(s). Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead (see the note about IE on the MDN page).

Beware that preventing default for the `touchstart` event on the `window` or `document` will disable scrolling of the descending areas.

To prevent the scrolling of the document but leave all the other events intact prevent default for the first `touchmove` event following `touchstart`:

```
var firstMove;

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    firstMove = true;
});

window.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    if (firstMove) {
        e.preventDefault();

        firstMove = false;
    }
});
```

The reason this works is that mobile Safari is using the first move to determine if body of the document is being scrolled. I have realised this while devising a more sophisticated solution.

In case this would ever stop working, the more sophisticated solution is to inspect the `touchTarget` element and its parents and make a map of directions that can be scrolled to. Then use the first `touchmove` event to detect the scroll direction and see if it is going to scroll the document or the target element (or either of the target element parents):

```
var touchTarget,
    touchScreenX,
    touchScreenY,
    conditionParentUntilTrue,
    disableScroll,
    scrollMap;

conditionParentUntilTrue = function (element, condition) {
    var outcome;

    if (element === document.body) {
        return false;
    }

    outcome = condition(element);

    if (outcome) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return conditionParentUntilTrue(element.parentNode, condition);
    }
};

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    touchTarget = e.targetTouches[0].target;
    // a boolean map indicating if the element (or either of element parents, excluding the document.body) can be scrolled to the X direction.
    scrollMap = {}

    scrollMap.left = conditionParentUntilTrue(touchTarget, function (element) {
        return element.scrollLeft > 0;
    });

    scrollMap.top = conditionParentUntilTrue(touchTarget, function (element) {
        return element.scrollTop > 0;
    });

    scrollMap.right = conditionParentUntilTrue(touchTarget, function (element) {
        return element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth &&
               element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth > element.scrollLeft;
    });

    scrollMap.bottom =conditionParentUntilTrue(touchTarget, function (element) {
        return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight &&
               element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight > element.scrollTop;
    });

    touchScreenX = e.targetTouches[0].screenX;
    touchScreenY = e.targetTouches[0].screenY;
    disableScroll = false;
});

window.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    var moveScreenX,
        moveScreenY;

    if (disableScroll) {
        e.preventDefault();

        return;
    }

    moveScreenX = e.targetTouches[0].screenX;
    moveScreenY = e.targetTouches[0].screenY;

    if (
        moveScreenX > touchScreenX && scrollMap.left ||
        moveScreenY < touchScreenY && scrollMap.bottom ||
        moveScreenX < touchScreenX && scrollMap.right ||
        moveScreenY > touchScreenY && scrollMap.top
    ) {
        // You are scrolling either the element or its parent.
        // This will not affect document.body scroll.
    } else {
        // This will affect document.body scroll.

        e.preventDefault();

        disableScroll = true;
    }
});
```

The reason this works is that mobile Safari is using the first touch move to determine if the document body is being scrolled or the element (or either of the target element parents) and sticks to this decision.

Comment: You sir, deserve a beer!

Comment: The second code snippet worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: If only you could actually wrap it in a usuable copy and paste, ready to use function

Comment: Hmm it seems to be blocking it altogether meaning that nothing scrolls

Comment: Seems that the `firstmove` method doesn't work on iOS 13 anymore. All elements are now blocked from scrolling.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using jquery 1.7+, this works well:

```
$("donotscrollme").on("touchmove", false);
```

Comment: If you have done this, is there a way to enable scrolling on a child element of "donotscrollme"?

Comment: Good question. You could try $("scrollme").on("touchmove", true); - not sure if that will work though.

Comment: @Pirkka Esko - you could try `$(elem).removeClass('donotscrollme');`

Comment: @PirkkaEsko You can try $("parent child").on("touchmove", false);

Answer (score 13):

This should work. No more gray areas at the top or bottom:)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function blockMove() {
      event.preventDefault() ;
}
</script>

<body ontouchmove="blockMove()">
```

But this also disables any scrollable areas. If you want to keep your scrollable areas and still remove the rubber band effect at the top and bottom, see here: https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix.

Comment: That bit.ly link isn't working.  Do you have the original URL?

Comment: The link is https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix. If a bit.ly link on a custom domain stops working, just change the domain to bit.ly (this link becomes http://bit.ly/uaIgUn)

Answer (score 10):

Disable:

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

Enable:

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ return true; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The page has to be launched from the Home screen for the meta tag to work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried above answers and particularly Gajus's but none works. Finally I found the answer below to solve the problem such that only the main body doesn't scroll but other scrolling sections inside my web app all work fine. 
Simply set position fixed for your body:

```
body {

height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This works well, especially if you never change it in the experience. If this is something you'll toggle on/off, perhaps for when a modal is displayed, then you may want to account for users' scroll position, as it would get reset every time. For a large e-commerce site, I've used a library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock

Answer (score 1):

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

is actually the best choice i found out it allows you to still be able to tap on input fields as well as drag things using jQuery UI draggable but it stops the page from scrolling.