# How do I disable scrolling on an iPad webapp?

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, scroll

The usual:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){event.preventDefault();},false);
```

isn't working for me. I am trying to make my iPad webapp feel as native as possible.
Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable scrolling in an iPhone web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890361/disable-scrolling-in-an-iphone-web-application)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Put that handler on the `document` element directly, not on the `body`.

I've had success with the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', false);
```

This will also be useful if you want to handle different orientations:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landscape.css" media="all and (orientation:landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portrait.css" media="all and (orientation:portrait)">
```

Comment: Just curious, could you also put the handler on the `window` object?