# Parallax animations and iOS scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touchscreen, parallax

I've created a website using [SUPERSCROLLORAMA](http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/) plugin. I wasn't aware of the problems with parallax scrolling on iPad and iPhone. I've found out a little bit to late, and I'm thinking about the ways to solve this.

If I understand correctly, events are disabled on this devices while scrolling. So will I be able to make website act as it should, if I disable the native scrolling and implement another one, via JavaScript plugin?

I've already disabled the original scrolling using Alnitak's answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733703/how-do-i-disable-scrolling-on-an-ipad-webapp) question. I've tried to find some plugins to activate scrolling again, but the problem is, it has to be binded to the `document` since animations are fired there... Do you know the plugin that will do the trick? Is my solution even correct, or there is no solution for my case, I need to rewrite the script from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parallax scrolling plugin that works on mobile browsers (iOS too).
Have a look at [**Skrollr**](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). It doesn't depend on any other library, it has optional mobile js file and is very easy to use. Just read the documentation.