# how to prevent ipad from scrolling when user input any data

Tags: html, ios, ipad, scroll

Is there any way to stop this scrolling when user inputs data on ipad,i tried different things but does not work.

Is there any way to stop this scrolling.

here is my code

```
             <html lang = "en">
            <head>
            <title>formDemo.html</title>
            <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {  
                $(document).bind('touchmove', false);


          });

         </script>

         </head>
         <body>
        <h1>Form Demo</h1>
        <form>
       <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
       <input type="text"   name="name" id="inputtext"  onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0); value="" style="margin:400px 0 0 0;" />
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: you mean you are working on a website, not a `UIWebView`, right ?

Comment: yes i am working on website in html not UIWebView UIWebView is in native in objective c

Answer (score 1):

Your question is almost answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7733750/188331). You only have to combine your logic with:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', false); // or true, depends you want to disable / enable
```

Comment: please see my updated question i am using same as you have asked but it is not working

Comment: it didn't scroll . in fact, it does not have enough contents to scroll. See: http://static.raptor.hk/noscroll.html Are you talking about bouncing effect of Mobile Safari ?