# Disable iOS Overscroll but allow body scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, web-applications

I would like to disable the iOS overscroll in a webapp but still allow the body to be scrolled.

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

disables scrolling altogether (as one would expect).

Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: It is an answer to a related question, though it covers this issue as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890361/disable-scrolling-in-an-iphone-web-application/26853900?stw=2#26853900.

Comment: I have found this script which fix this problem! :) https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had pretty much the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238084/ios-safari-how-to-disable-overscroll-but-allow-scrollable-divs-to-scroll-norma). This should help you:

```
// Disable overscroll / viewport moving on everything but scrollable divs
 $('body').on('touchmove', function (e) {
         if (!$('.scrollable').has($(e.target)).length) e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: One challenge with this is that if you've scrolled all the way to the top or bottom, you can still overscroll the entire page!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
     if(!$(e.target).hasClass("scrollable")) {
       e.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

Try this i just got in via google

Comment: Yer so I added the scrollable class to body (because that's what I want to be able to scroll) but it still leaves the body unscrollable (and removes the overscroll)