# Prevent body scroll on touch devices when scrolling on modal

Tags: mobile, modal-dialog, touch

I'm working on a web app that uses lots of modal overlays with scrollable content in the modal . On touch devices, and in particular on Android, the mobile browser wants to scroll the body content behind the modal instead of the actual scrollable content area within the modal.  Or, if the content does scroll, when it hits the top or bottom of the scrollable area, the scrolling then continues on the body. I don't want the body to scroll at all under any circumstances when the modal is visible/active.

I tried to prevent this with the following code but it seems to have no effect (in this case, `$context` is the document root):

```
$context.on('touchmove touchstart touchend', '[data-modal-content]', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Anyone have other ideas/insight?

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I am having the same problem with the body scrolling in the background when i have a scroll in the modal.

Comment: I think i got it working by altering the css on the body to `overflow-y:hidden;` then switching it back when the modal closes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with the provided z-index of your elements? Maybe the Modal itself or an inner container isn't stacked on top of the body-text

Comment: I checked this already and there is no z-index problem. everything is stacked properly.  It behaves sort of like if you were using a mouse wheel on a single z-index layer with two or more scrollable areas. When you hit the bottom or top of the scrollable area, then the scrolling continues on the body scroll bar.  But in desktop, I have completely disabled scrolling on the body.  This however does not seem to disable touch scrolling.