# Boostrap Modal Scrolling on iOS after changing size of modal body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Url: http://download.ivanfillini.com/?go > click on one of the images

Problem:
Modal and scrooling the modal works fine on iOS devices until you change the size of the modal (e.g. by changin "Dein Land" to "Deutschland"). I have tried several tips of other stackoverflow questions (fixed > absulute, -moz-...=touch, max-height, [Prevent body scroll on touch devices when scrolling on modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016369/prevent-body-scroll-on-touch-devices-when-scrolling-on-modal), ...) but nothing works for my solution.

(another question: after closing modal I can't click again on same link until I open a different link?)

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?