# Interrupt iOS scrolling using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, mobile-safari

Is there way to interrupt iOS scrolling using javascript?

Example 1: user is scrolling content by moving his finger through device screen. When some event happens user continue moving his finger without raising but there is no scrolling anymore.

Example 2: user initiated scrolling but stopped his finger without raising. Some event happens and scrollbar disappears.

Example 3: Momentum scrolling completely stops when some event happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about interrupting the iOS inertia/momentum scrolling, then I might have something for you.

First of all, you need to add [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick). The lib removes the 300ms click delay on mobile devices and enables event capturing during inertia/momentum scrolling.

After including fastclick and attaching it to the body element, my code to interrupt scrolling looks like this:

```
scrollElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
setTimeout(function() {
  scrollElement.style.overflow = '';
}, 10);
```

The trick is to set `overflow: hidden`, which stops the inertia/momentum scrolling. Please see my fiddle for a full implementation of [stop scrolling during inertia/momentum](http://jsfiddle.net/6EYxz/).

Answer (score 1):

The first case could probably be covered using the following piece of code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175312/1091402)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function blockMove() {
      event.preventDefault() ;
}
</script>

<body ontouchmove="blockMove()">
```

However, it will [only work on iOS 8+](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/). As for the other two cases I'm not aware of any method to do that.

Comment: It is not possible to interrupt scrolling in progress by event.preventDefault()